# How do I trap a function inputs using powermock?

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, hbase, powermock, powermockito

Lets say I have the function to test as below:

```
boolean MyFunction (String input1, Text rowkey) {
   int a = 10;
   a = a + 10;
   return context.write(rowkey,a);
}
```

Note that context.write is a function that writes to a database.

I would like to mock that function and check whether the inputs that are passed to it are correct. How do I do this?

Basically, can i do something like the below (which I cant seem to get to work):

```
   PowerMockito.when(Context.write((Text) anyObject(),
  (int) anyObject())).then(compareResult(input1,input2));

 private Answer<Boolean> compareResults(input1, input2) {
     AssertTrue(input1,this.Test1Input1AcceptanceCriteria)
     AssertTrue(input2,this.Test1Input2AcceptanceCriteria)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that I worked out myself and works perfectly as I need it to. I test all my map-reduce code effectively with this technique without help from mrunit as well.

```
@Test
public void testMyFunction () throws Exception {
   Context testContext = mock(Context.class);
   MyFunction (input1, rowkey); // Call the function under test
   // Now here is the magic. We use the verify technique to test 
   // the mocked class method while checking for equality with the acceptance criteria.
   // In essence, the key is trap these underlying functions and ensure that
   // they are passed in the right input from your function under test.
   int expected_input_to_write = 10
   Mockito.verify(testContext).write(eq((Object) new Text("test_string")), eq((Object) expected_input_to_write )); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to do so!

Assuming that *context* is a *field* of your enclosing class, then you "simply" have to find a way to provide a **mocked** version of such a *context* object to your class under test.

The typical way here: **dependency injection**

Like:

```
public class Foo {
   private final Context context;

   // some external constructor that you would use to create Foo objects
   public Foo() { this (new Context(...)); }

   // an internall ctor, used by your unit tests
   Foo(Context context) { this.context = context;  }
```

And then, you can write unit tests such as

```
@Test
public void testMyFunction() {
  Context context = ... create some mock
  Foo underTest = new Foo(context);
  underTest.myFunction(...
```

Using the above approach, your whole need for **Power** mocking vanishes. You can use "ordinary" mocking frameworks such as Mokito or EasyMock to prepare/verify your context object!

You see, in the end, your problem is that the code that you created is simply **hard** to test, unless you start thinking about dependency injection. If you are serious about testing, watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79); they give you a broad introduction into how to actually create testable code.